# Glassfish 4 URL mapping

Tags: java, jsp, glassfish

Please help me, I cann't do this for 3rd day((

Here is my web.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
               http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
             version="3.0">

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>ebookshopservlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>
                ebookshop.ShoppingServlet
            </servlet-class>

        </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ebookshopservlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/eshop</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I have jsp project, and there is an issue with /ebookshop/eshop url, it constantly writes 404 error - not found. What is my mistake in configuring this web server and application?

there is my servlet

```
package ebookshop;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import ebookshop.Book;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

/**
 *
 * @author Ilqar
 */
public class ShoppingServlet extends HttpServlet{

    public void init(ServletConfig conf) throws ServletException {
        super.init(conf);
    }
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        doPost(req,res);
    }
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
           // @WebServlet(name = "ShoppingServlet", urlPatterns = {"/eshop"})

        HttpSession session;
        session = req.getSession();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Vector<Book> shoplist=(Vector<Book>) session.getAttribute("ebookshop.cart");
        String do_this=req.getParameter("do_this");

        if (do_this==null)
        {
           Vector<String> blist=new Vector<String>();
           blist.addElement("Learn HTML5 and JavaScript for iOS. Scott Preston $39.99");
           blist.addElement("Java 7 for Absolute Beginners. Jay Bryant $39.99");
           blist.addElement("Beginning Android 4. Livingston $39.99");
           blist.addElement("Pro Spatial with SQL Server 2012. Alastair Aitchinson $59.99");
           blist.addElement("Beginning Database Design. Clare Churcher $34.99");
           session.setAttribute("ebookshop.list", blist);

           ServletContext sc=getServletContext();
           RequestDispatcher rd=sc.getRequestDispatcher("/");
           rd.forward(req, res);
        }
        else {

            if (do_this.equals("checkout"))
            {
                float dollars=0;
                int books=0;
                for (Book abook: shoplist)
                {
                    dollars+=abook.getPrice()*abook.getQuantity();
                    books+=abook.getQuantity();
                }
                req.setAttribute("dollars", new Float(dollars).toString());
                req.setAttribute("books", new Integer(books).toString());
                ServletContext sc=getServletContext();
                RequestDispatcher rd=sc.getRequestDispatcher("/Checkout.jsp");
                rd.forward(req, res);
            } // end if (do_this.equals("checkout"))
            else {
            if (do_this.equals("remove")){
                String pos=req.getParameter("position");
                shoplist.removeElementAt((new Integer(pos)));
            }
            else if (do_this.equals("add"))
            {
                boolean found=false;
                Book abook=getBook(req);

                if (shoplist==null)
                {
                    shoplist=new Vector<Book>();
                    shoplist.addElement(abook);
                }
                else 
                {
                    for (int i=0;i<shoplist.size() && !found;i++)
                    {
                        Book b= (Book) shoplist.elementAt(i);
                        if (b.getTitle().equals(abook.getTitle()))
                        {
                            b.setQuantity(b.getQuantity()+abook.getQuantity());
                            shoplist.setElementAt(b, i);
                            found=true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!found)
                    {
                        shoplist.addElement(abook);
                    }
                }
            }
            session.setAttribute("ebookshop.cart", shoplist);
            ServletContext sc=getServletContext();
            RequestDispatcher rd=sc.getRequestDispatcher("/");

            rd.forward(req, res);

            }
        }
}

    public Book getBook(HttpServletRequest req){

        String myBook=req.getParameter("book");
        int n=myBook.indexOf("$");
        String name=myBook.substring(0, n);
        String price=myBook.substring(n+1);
        String qty=req.getParameter("qty");

        return new Book(name,Float.parseFloat(price),Integer.parseInt(qty));
    }
}
```

and my index.jsp file

```
<%-- 
    Document   : ebookshop_index
    Created on : 22.07.2015, 21:33:24
    Author     : Ilqar
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true"%>
<%@page session="true" import="java.util.*,ebookshop.Book" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>E-bookshop</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {background-color: gray; font-size: 10pt;}
            h1 {font-size: 20pt}
            table {background-color: white;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Your online Bookshop!</h1>

        <% //Scriplet 1 checks whether the booklist is ready
            Vector<ebookshop.Book> booklist=(Vector<ebookshop.Book>)session.getAttribute("ebookshop.list");

            if (booklist==null)
            {
                response.sendRedirect("/ebookshop/eshop");
            }
            else {
        %>
        <form name="addForm" method="POST" action="eshop">
            <input type="hidden" name="do_this" value="add">
            Book:
            <select name="book">

                <% //Scriplet the booklist to the selection control
                for (int i=0;i<booklist.size();i++)
                {
                out.println("<option>"+booklist.elementAt(i).getTitle()+"</option>");
                }
                %>

            </select>
                Quantity: <input type="text" name="qty" value="1" size="3">
                <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart">
        </form>
                <p/>

                <%  //Scriplet 3 check whether the shopping cart is empty
                Vector shoplist=
        (Vector<ebookshop.Book>)session.getAttribute("ebookshop.cart");
                if ((shoplist!=null) && (shoplist.size()>0)){
%>          
<table style="border: 1px; padding: 2px">
    <tr>
        <td>TITLE</td>
        <td>PRICE</td>
        <td>QUANTITY</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <% //Scriplet show the books in shopping cart
        for (int i=0;i<shoplist.size();i++)
        {
         Book aBook=(Book)shoplist.elementAt(i);

         %>
         <tr>
         <form name="removeForm" action="eshop" method="POST">
             <input type="hidden" name="position" value="<%=i%>">
             <input type="hidden" name="do_this" value="remove">
             <td>
                 <%=aBook.getTitle()%>
             </td>
             <td style="text-align: right">
                 <%=aBook.getPrice()%>
             </td>
              <td style="text-align: right">
                 <%=aBook.getQuantity()%>
             </td>
         </form>
         </tr>
         <%
        }
    %>
</table> 
<p/>
<form name="checkoutForm" action="eshop" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" value="checkout" name="do_this">
    <input type="submit" value="Checkout">
</form>
<%
                }
            }
%>
    </body>
</html>
```

I guess it sends redirect to the servlet when session attribute is null

Comment: URL pattern of `/eshop/.*` perhaps?

Comment: didn't work, the same 404 error

Comment: Sorry, try `/eshop/*` - the dot was my mistake. (It may not work, but it's worth trying...)

Comment: Hmm. Anything in the logs at all?

Comment: [2015-07-31T19:58:57.952+0500] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.web.core] [tid: _ThreadID=35 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1438354737952] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Suspicious url pattern: "/eshop/.*" in context [/ebookshop] - see section SRV.11.2 of the Servlet specification]]

Comment: Well yes, I suggested that you remove the `.`.

Comment: [2015-07-31T22:00:08.800+0500] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00172] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=33 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1438362008800] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Loading application [ebookshop] at [/ebookshop]]]

Comment: Okay, so that suggests it's loaded the right servlet. Now you should look at the servlet to work out what's wrong.

Comment: I added servlet code and jsp file text in topic

Comment: Well now's a time to get debugging...

Comment: it didn't give an error, entered into first if

if (do_this==null) added elements and  exited with

ServletContext sc=getServletContext();
           RequestDispatcher rd=sc.getRequestDispatcher("/");
           rd.forward(req, res);

Answer (score 0):

It worked! I have forgotten to put annotation before the servlett class, that is why it couldn't find the page. Author of the book didn't put, maybe cause it wasn't used that time. I just put

@WebServlet(name = "ShoppingServlet", urlPatterns = {"/eshop"})

and standart web.xml and all worked! I used Tomcat server, and hope it will work for Glassfish also.